# Write a program that use a loop to display the integers entered by the user from smallest to larger

Tags: java, file, loops, if-statement

where the user enter a series of integers in a loop.  The user enter -99 to signal the end of the series.Where all of the integer will be save in a file. After all the numbers have been entered, the program should read all of the integers save in the file and display all of  numbers from smallest to largest.

I been trying but I just cant figure out, how to display the integers in order.Now I'm stuck.Ask you are able to see, I  did not use any fancy programming,  such as array or list, because I'm still learning about classes and had not learn any of that yet. Please help! and thank you, I'm still a beginner.

```
package chapter4;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.Random;

public class ProChallenge10 {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

        int integer =0; //Integer enter by the user.

        boolean signal = false; // To end the loop.

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Created the file for the integers entered. 
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("ProChallenge10.txt"); 

        //Let the user enter a series of numbers.
        while(signal == false){

            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
            integer = keyboard.nextInt();

            outputFile.println(integer);

        //To end the program.
        if(integer == -99){
            signal = true;
            //Close the outputFile.
            outputFile.close();
            } 
        }

         //Open the file and read input from the file.
         File file = new File("ProChallenge10.txt");
         Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

         //Read all of the values from the file and display their numbers. 
         while(inputFile.hasNext()){

            int number = inputFile.nextInt();

           }
         //Close the InputFile.
         inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You add them to a `List`, then `sort()` the list.

Comment: I don't even see an attempt to see if the numbers are in order or to change their order...

Comment: Hmm. As a CS Major, this looks like professor code that you have to add to... What have you tried?

Comment: @DovahkiinvasNormandy Your professors give out example code with things like `while(signal == false){`? Oh dear.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Hahaha, god no. I meant as far as the formatting goes. It's very neat with comments on all of the parts. Indicative of not beginner/early student code. Plus the bloody package name is `chapter4`

Comment: @DovahkiinvasNormandy, oh no this code has not been given by my professor, I'm not taking any classes as of right now, I'm just trying to improve my skills in Java. I, by myself wrote this code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, Hey, is informal to write the code , `while(signal == false)` ?this was the only idea that came to my mind.

Comment: @JulioRosario When we iterate "normally" we might use `while (signal == true)` which is a long way of writing `while (signal)` (read as While Signal). We can similarly write an expression with the negation of the shorter form; that is `while (!signal)` (which can be read as While Not Signal). See also, [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). **Negation** is a very important concept to master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them to the `List` then `sort()` before printing it to the text file.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ProChallenge10 {

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

    int integer =0; //Integer enter by the user.

    boolean signal = false; // To end the loop.

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Integer> listofInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();// Array List for your integers

    //Created the file for the integers entered. 
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("ProChallenge10.txt"); 

    //Let the user enter a series of numbers.
    while(signal == false){

        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        integer = keyboard.nextInt();

        listofInt.add(integer);// adding of int to list


    //To end the program.
    if(integer == -99){
        listofInt.sort(null);// sort the list
        for(int x=0;x<listofInt.size();x++){
            outputFile.println(listofInt.get(x));//Printing of list to text file
        }
        signal = true;
        //Close the outputFile.
        outputFile.close();
        } 
    }

     //Open the file and read input from the file.
     File file = new File("ProChallenge10.txt");
     Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

     //Read all of the values from the file and display their numbers. 
     while(inputFile.hasNext()){

        int number = inputFile.nextInt();

       }
     //Close the InputFile.
     inputFile.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Huh, I actually didn't know list.sort(null) sorted that way. Neato.

Comment: @DovahkiinvasNormandy I'm also fairly new to java. But it worked for me, sorted smallest to largest.

Comment: @DovahkiinvasNormandy I can show you ProChallenge10.txt if you like or you can try the code out. If there is anything wrong please tell me. For learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

At risk of doing your homework for you, starting with the `//Open the file and read input from the file.` comment down, if you replace it or just add in these changes, this will sort from smallest to largest and output to the console window:

```
     //Open the file and read input from the file.
     File file = new File("ProChallenge10.txt");
     Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
     ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     //Read all of the values from the file and display their numbers. 
     while(inputFile.hasNext()){

        Integer number = inputFile.nextInt();
        arrList.add(number);

       }
    Collections.sort(arrList, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer integer1, Integer integer2)
    {
        return  integer1.compareTo(integer2);
    }
});
     //Close the InputFile.
     inputFile.close();

     //Display the sorted numbers
     for(Integer number : arrList){
         System.out.println(number);
     }
```

If you need to put the sorted numbers back into the file, I'll leave that up to you to do as the tools are at your disposal already. If you want to know how this is working I'll gladly reply when I get the chance.

And as a F.Y.I. your getting downvoted to oblivion because you showed no effort. I upvoted because I know what it's like starting out and everyone deserves some slack. But show more effort for your next post.